# IE 9 and jQuery(this).remove(); fails until page reload on img tag

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

In Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, I'm successfully using onError to remove images that didn't load:

```
<img src="" onerror="jQuery(this).remove();" />
```

This doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer 9, but the second+ refresh of the page works fine and exactly like the other browsers.  Is there a better way to remove img tags from the dom that didn't load correctly in IE?  It almost seems like IE is indefinitely waiting for images to load on the first page load?

Comment: Please post a *Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example* of the issue so we can better diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the error is being returned from the image before jQuery has loaded. This would cause the onerror handler to fire, but it would then fail.

This doesn't really need to be done with jQuery at all; you could use a regular Javascript to deal with it. Something like this should do the trick:

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

That would be a direct replacement for the jQuery code you currently have. A similar amount of code and removes the need for jQuery, so removes any possible problem caused by loading sequence.

It's also worth pointing out that one of jQuery's main reasons for existing is to help us get rid of the need for JS code embedded in the HTML like this, so seeing a jQuery call inside an HTML event like as per your original example just looks wrong.

If you are going to use jQuery for this, don't do it that that; use jquery's proper event handling mechanisms. It would look like this:

```
jQuery('img').error(function() {
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

This would be in a separate script tag, outside of your HTML.

However, due to the issues of loading sequence, and the fact that your image loading errors will occur very early in the page load, I would suggest just going with the first solution. The jQuery solution might be more worthwhile if you have images loading dynamically after the main page load though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using knockoutjs to load the images through templates.  Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this in my opinion is pending on your server-side scripting. Do a file check, if the file exists, then load it with the rest, if not then don't render it skip it for the next or something. But thats my opinion, and theres always the fluke that something will go wrong I supose while its downloading. I notice your using

`onError`

Iver personally never used this, but from all the examples I have seen in time its always been

`onerror`

A lot of browsers try to look for these attributes in a case-insensitive way, and try to correct it themselves to render an output the way it needs to. However IE, has and always will be very finicky as to what it looks for. I'd say just for giggles, try doing it lower-case and see if it doesn't pick up every time like its supposed to, if it does then this is your problem, if not like someone posted in your comments, give us a little insight code wise what you are attempting to do so we can try to better aid you with what going wrong where.

Comment: Thanks for the fix.  Apparently some browsers tolerate the onError, but it wasn't consistent across browsers.  As far as Server Side Scripting, that's a good idea to filter out images prior to loading.  I'm using Dot Net Nuke as a server and don't want to create ASP.NET web forms.  Rather, I'm dropping in Javascript in DNN pages and working entirely cross domain in an ASP.NET MVC 4 API website.  It's far less difficulties for me.